# Run Jenkins plugin after build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a following pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "im a build"'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            myPlugin()
        }
    }
}
```

And now in `myPlugin` I wanna have a build result. Try to do it like:

```
public class MyPluginPublisher extends Notifier implements SimpleBuildStep {
    @DataBoundConstructor
    public MyPluginPublisher() {
    }

    @Override
    public MyPluginDescriptor getDescriptor() {
        return (MyPluginDescriptor) super.getDescriptor();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean needsToRunAfterFinalized() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Action getProjectAction(AbstractProject<?, ?> project) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(@Nonnull Run<?, ?> build, @Nonnull FilePath filePath, @Nonnull Launcher launcher, @Nonnull TaskListener taskListener) throws IOException {
        taskListener.getLogger().format("build result " + build.getResult() + "\n");
        taskListener.getLogger().format("isBuilding " + build.isBuilding() + "\n");
    }
}
```

As you can see, I use a `needsToRunAfterFinalized` method to signalize that plugin should wait for builds end, but build result is null.

Following output form log is printed:

```
build result null
isBuilding true
```

what should I do to run this plugin after build completion and obtain a result.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the post build step is part of the build process. I fyou want to have a build status why not using :

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('test') {
        steps {
            sh 'echo "im a build"'
        }
    }
}
post {
    success {
        echo 'build success'
    }
    failure {
        echo 'build failed'
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: And there is no any other options to handle plugin after finalize all build stuff?

Comment: There are the post build task plugin => https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task also for that.